# WebDeploy with VS2015 ignores web.config transform

Tags: webdeploy, visual-studio-2015

I opened an existing project in VS2015, made some small changes and published the MVC application to my webserver with an existing WebDeploy publishing profile. This broke the application because the web.config file on the server was overwritten with the original one for my developers machine. I have checked the settings in the Publish-wizard but the configuration was like always before. I could fix the application by manually changing the web.config on production but am afraid now to publish again.

Has anything changed in the WebDeploy publishing method with web.config transformation?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. In my case the publishing profile was renamed to "servername (production)" and the configuration setting for the transformation was only web.servername.config. After changing the name of the publishing profile to the exact same name as the config setting it worked.